# getJSON callback not firing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm making the call using the following script which is called on click of an anchor tag

```
function GetToken(videoId) {
  debugger;
  var json = $.getJSON("/Vod/RequestAccessToken/" + videoId, function(result) {
    alert("token recieved: " + result.token);
  });
}
```

In the server application I receive the call so I know it is a valid URL, but the callback is not being invoked.  If i set though the jquery code (f11/f10) the callback is called??!!!?

Server returns results from MVC application in the form of a class

```
// function called
public JsonResult RequestAccessToken(int id)
{
    Token t = new Token();
    t.MasterId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var result = new TokenResult(t.MasterId);
    return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

// class returned
public class TokenResult
{
    public TokenResult() { }
    public TokenResult(Guid g) { token = g.ToString(); }
    public string token = null;
}
```

When I access the url via browser result =

```
{
  "token":"c877453e-739d-4883-9310-91ddd707d6af"
}
```

Answer (score 23):

If your result is not successful, that callback won't fire, this is usually due to invalid JSON being returned.  To give it a test, you can use the long form of `$.getJSON`, like this so you can see the error:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result){
    alert("token recieved: " + result.token);
  },
  error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
  },
  complete: function(request, textStatus) { //for additional info
    alert(request.responseText);
    alert(textStatus);
  }
});
```

If it is a JSON/parser error, you can take your response and see what's wrong with JSONLint, here: http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Marty - What error *are* you getting...it's there for a reason, always post it.

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  It's failing silently. 

json result = 
{"token":"c877453e-739d-4883-9310-91ddd707d6af"}

Comment: @Marty - Try my updated answer, see what the complete throws out, it really does seem like a parsing error silently failing, see what the complete method above alerts for the **exact** responseText, need to see the literal response to check for anything invalid.

Comment: IE == Nothing Happends (debuggers aren't even hit)

FF == Error, blank, error

Answer (score 3):

A likely bet is that you're not returning valid JSON.  The jQuery docs note that, "As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently."   Does the JSON text you're serving pass [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/)?  You may also want to switch (at least temporarily) to [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  It allows more error handling.  Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Vod/RequestAccessToken/"+videoId,
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){

        },
  success: function(result){
            alert("token recieved: " + result.token);
        }
});
```

Comment: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ can be useful online tool in spotting errors. Just paste the json there on the left side.

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.

<strike>So, is your JSON valid?</strike>

```
function GetToken(videoId) {
    debugger;
    console.log('getting it');
    var json = $.get("/Vod/RequestAccessToken/"+videoId, function(result){
        console.log('got it');
    });
}
```

What does the above output? (Assuming your browser has a `console`.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling preventDefault() or returning false in the anchor's click handler?

Answer (score 0):

You need to signal to allow JSONGets in your controller action when calling the Serialization Json method:

```
 public JsonResult ActionDateClicked(ActionViewModel vm)
        {
            vm.Model.Observation = "Changed";
            return Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```