# Getting JSON data back in error.responeText

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I'm trying to get some JSON data from a file on my server and for some reason it's not working but throughs an error. But if I log error.responseText I can see my data there!?

I'm using this function

```
function getJson(url) {

var result;
 $.getJSON(url, function(data){

    console.log('success');

}).error(function(error){

    result = error.responseText;
    console.log("Error: " + result);

    return result;
});
```

}

Does anyone know why?

Comment: It is possible that you are not getting valid json out of that url. what is the current output post that too in the question post above.

Comment: you should look here, it's probably going to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716468/getjson-callback-not-firing

Comment: Thanks, was just a simple syntax error in the JSON file :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **fail** function.

```
function getJson(url) {

  var result;
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){

   console.log('success');

  }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){

  result = textStatus + ", " + error;
  console.log("Error: " + result);

  return result; 
});
```